# Why is my specified range in PROC IMPORT being ignored?

Tags: import, sas

I am trying to import a set of exchange rates. The data set lookes like this:

[image]
[image]

That is to say the actual data should be read from row 5 and downwards from the sheet named "Växelkurser". The variable names should be read from row 4.

I try writing the following code:

```
PROC IMPORT 
DATAFILE="/opt3/01_Dataleveranser/03_IBIS/Inläsning/IBIS3/Växelkurser macrobond/Växelkurser19DEC2022.xlsx"
OUT=WORK.VALUTOR_0000
DBMS=xlsx
REPLACE;
sheet="Växelkurser";
getnames=yes;
range="Växelkurser$A4:0";
RUN;
```

And I get the following result:

[image]

I clearly specified that SAS should start reading from the fourth row and that the variable names should be read from that row. Why is this being ignored and how would I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are specifying both `sheet=` and `range=`. The `sheet` statement is telling SAS to read the whole sheet and I think this is overriding the later `range` statment.

Remove the following line and the code should work as expected:

```
sheet="Växelkurser";
```